# JSPDF Autotable breaks rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

In web app I'm using the JSPDF Autotable to build a PDF. 
The problem is that the data will be dynamic (I'm going to use AngularJS 1.x) and so the rows can have differents height.

In some cases, Autotable breaks the last row of the page, continuing to the next one. How can I prevent this behavior, and set up Autotable to take the last row (which default would break) and bring it to the next page?

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/9vgxvfkh/1/

I guess I have to change some settings in the style:

```
styles: {
    cellPadding: 1.5,
    overflow: 'linebreak',
    valign: 'middle',
    halign: 'center',
    lineColor: [0, 0, 0],
    lineWidth: 0.2 
},
pageBreak: 'always'
```

But I tried, and it didn't work.

P.S.: The margin top on the header is because then I will add an image.

Comment: Please check updated answer. Is that solution acceptable for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do it using some parameters or styles.

I did a quick debug and found a solution for your problem, you need to modify the source code slightly.

[image]

In the source code I found that, for each row a method `printFullRow` is called, after that there is a check if the row can fit on the page (method `canFitOnPage`).

If row cannot fit on page, there is a check how many lines of text does it contain (in my case it is 10). Row is being split, because number of lines is bigger than 1.

You need to change this number to something bigger. In order to avoid further bugs you need to ensure how many lines would fit entire page height and put this number instead of 1. If you would choose some enormous amount, in case of really long text that wouldn't even fit entire page, it wouldn't be rendered at all, because `common_1.addPage()` would be executed endlessly.

To sum up, change line 470 to something like this:

```
if (row.maxLineCount <= 50) {
```

Unless 50 lines can't fit on page...

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Please check updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9vgxvfkh/2/

Comment: Perfect! If using the `min` version of the script, it is `e.maxLineCount`. Just search for `<=` and you should be able to locate the part to change.

Answer (score 8):

Using the latest version this particular example is fixed. But for other cases where you don't want a multi line row to be split you can use `rowPageBreak: 'avoid'`.